# Need to connect to mongodb database present in a server

Tags: spring, mongodb

I am working in an organization and I am supposed to connect to a mongodb database in one of the servers. As of now I have robomongo installed in my local machine and with that I can open the database and do operations like make collections and stuff.

I don't have mongodb installed in my local machine

But now I am trying to do it through spring , so do I need to install mongodb in my local machine??

Note: the database has credentials like username and password

Comment: Well you can probably just connect to their server. But if I were the client I would really appreciate if you did your learning on your own data, and would prefer you install your own instance and make mistakes there first.

Comment: I made  my own collection there and want to try out things with that collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to install MongoDB locally. The programming framework (in your case, Spring) will include a suitable [driver](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/) which is capable of connecting to the MongoDB server.

Comment: Okay got it thank you so much, I am also having difficulty with getting a spring bean setup so that it can take the database credentials. Can you help me that?

Comment: Sorry Vishal Roy, that's outside the scope of this Q&A site. You need to find yourself a suitable tutorial - there should be plenty if you search for them.